# Passing multiple arguments through twig path

Tags: symfony, twig

I have this twig code:

```
<div style="padding-left: 5em" class="comment">
    <p>{{ comment.author.name }} - {{ comment.created|date('j. n. Y H:i') }}</p>
    <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>
    <p><a href="{{ path('comment_response_new', {'id': post.id, 'idc': comment.id}) }}">Odpovědět na komentář</a></p>

    {% for child in comment.children %}
        {% include 'BlogApplicationBundle:Post:_comment.html.twig' with {'comment' : child}%}
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

and this is function that processes the output from link in twig code:

```
/**
     * @Route("/post/{id}/newcommentresponse", name="comment_response_new")
     * @Template("BlogApplicationBundle:Post:form.html.twig")
     */
    public function commentResponceAction($id,$idc)
    {
        $comment = new Comment();
        $form = $this->createForm(new CommentType(), $comment);

        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        );
}
```

when i try to run code i get this error :

> Controller "Cvut\Fit\BiWt1\Blog\ApplicationBundle\Controller\CommentController::commentResponceAction()"
>   requires that you provide a value for the "$idc" argument (because
>   there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument
>   after this one).

So it seems that second argument passsed through link is ignored and i have no idea what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `$idc` definition in your [@Route](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html) annotation.  It should look something like this:

```
@Route("/post/{id}/newcommentresponse/{idc}", name="comment_response_new")
```

or this:

```
@Route("/post/{id}/{idc}/newcommentresponse", name="comment_response_new")
```

You can also leave it out of the route and function declaration and grab it directly from the Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/post/{id}/newcommentresponse", name="comment_response_new")
 * @Template("BlogApplicationBundle:Post:form.html.twig")
 */
public function commentResponceAction($id)
{
    $idc = $request->query->get('idc');
```